# hadoop not found when ./hcat_server.sh start was run

Tags: hadoop, hive, hcatalog

I want to run Hcatalog, for this I fired the below query:
mohnish@mohnish:/usr/lib/hive/hcatalog/sbin$ ./hcat_server.sh start
I found the below error:
Hadoop not found.

can you help identify where the issue is..

Comment: Can anybody please reply here...

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should put this line in HIVE_HOME/bin/hive-config.sh

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/path/to/hadoop
```

Of course, First of all,

You must install hadoop.